# C# JSON JavaScriptSerializer object parsing

Tags: c#, json, parsing, object, javascriptserializer

;-)
i have a problem to parse JSON response to an object.

I have following object:

```
public class Conferences : List<ConferenceData>
{

}

public class ConferenceData
{
    private string _id;
    private string _title;
    private string _conference_code;
    private string _conference_state;
    private string _conference_type;
    private string _datetime_start;
    private int? _dial_type;
    private string _moderator_code;
    private int? _max_participants_count;


    public string id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }
    public string title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { _title = value; }
    }
    public string datetime_start
    {
        get { return _datetime_start; }
        set { _datetime_start = value; }
    }
    public int? duration { get; set; }
    public int? dial_type
    {
        get { return _dial_type; }
        set { _dial_type = value; }
    }
    public string conference_type
    {
        get { return _conference_type; }
        set { _conference_type = value; }
    }

    public string conference_state
    {
        get { return _conference_state; }
        set { _conference_state = value; }
    }

    public bool? auto_recording { get; set; }
    public string cost_centre { get; set; }
    public int? participants_count { get; set; }
    public int? security_code { get; set; }
    public List<Participant> participants { get; set; }
    public bool? broadcast_only_flag { get; set; }
    public string moderator_code
    {
        get { return _moderator_code; }
        set { _moderator_code = value; }
    }
```

And following logic:

```
string json = "[{\"conference\":{\"conference_code\":\"208475\",\"conference_state\":\"planned\",\"conference_type\":\"scheduled\",\"datetime_start\":\"2013-04-30T15:30:00+02:00\",\"dial_type\":1,\"id\":\"7\",\"moderator_code\":\"652929\",\"scheduled_participants_count\":null,\"title\":\"betreff\"}},{\"conference\":{\"conference_code\":\"502012\",\"conference_state\":\"planned\",\"conference_type\":\"scheduled\",\"datetime_start\":\"2013-04-30T16:30:00+02:00\",\"dial_type\":1,\"id\":\"11\",\"moderator_code\":\"133140\",\"scheduled_participants_count\":null,\"title\":\"Betreff\"}},{\"conference\":{\"conference_code\":\"530437\",\"conference_state\":\"planned\",\"conference_type\":\"scheduled\",\"datetime_start\":\"2013-05-02T10:24:14+02:00\",\"dial_type\":1,\"id\":\"15\",\"moderator_code\":\"903257\",\"scheduled_participants_count\":null,\"title\":\"Test ui\"}}]";

    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    Conferences conferences = serializer.Deserialize<Conferences>(json);
```

What's wrong? I have try a lot of different object typs,.. arry, list, dictionary, collection,... I can't find the right typ,... :-(

Best regards!
Marc

Comment: What's wrong? You tell *us*! What error are you getting?

Comment: System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object] is not a value of the type WindowsFormsApplication2.ConferenceData and can't use in this generic list. Parametername: value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare a class

```
public class Conference
{
    public ConferenceData conference;
}
```

and deserialize as

```
var conferences = serializer.Deserialize<List<Conference>>(json);
```